# Seemingly pointless excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, spreadsheet, reactive-programming

I'm debugging a massive spreadsheet, and I've come across this wierd little formula in multiple places:

```
=IF(P6="", "", P6)
```

No matter what, that cell is going to be equal to P6. Any pointers as to why the original author from way back when didn't just go

```
=P6
```

instead?

I've made sure that there's no macro magic going on behind the scenes, throwing and catching events and whatnot.

Comment: was the original author paid by the number of characters in populated cells perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually (and I had to try this to be sure), `=P6` and `=IF(P6="", "", P6)` have different behaviors.  If `P6` is empty then `=P6` will return 0, while the formula will return an empty cell.  This looks like it is for formatting purposes, because an empty cell and 0 will behave the same way in aggregate functions like `SUM`.  Personally I find that "Accounting format" for numbers is cleaner where zero is represented as a discrete `-`.